# 100% width, padding and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, padding, css-position

I was trying to make a div fill a certain part of the screen, leaving 412px empty both to the left and to the right. Easy, eh?

Now, when I add position:absolute & top:0, the fill disappears. The element inspector shows it's empty - the "paddings" stay, but the width:100% disappears. I've used this code (without the positioning):

```
<div style="height:73px; padding-left:413px; padding-right:413px;">
  <div style="width:100%; height:73px; background:url(top-fill-small.png);">
  </div>
</div>
```

So, how can I position it absolutely (I need it animated later), while preserving the padding? I'd love your help very much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not mix CSS in your HTML: http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle

Comment: Thanks, I know. It was just for the sake of the speed of writing. When publishing, I'll separate it indeed. Once again, thanks for attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Perhaps this?](http://jsbin.com/exapo4)

```
<div style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0">
    <div style="height:73px; background:url(top-fill-small.png); margin-left:413px; margin-right:413px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, because, as I stated, I need it to leave 412px (in this case) both to the left and to the right. And this way... Just try it out and you'll see ;)  Thanks though :)

Comment: Then I don't yet understand what you want. [It does leave](http://i.imgur.com/DXjVH.png) 413px (412?) to the left and right. Is there a minimum width you want the div to have?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry, probably when replying, I've answered the wrong comment. This works. Very grateful, thank you!

Comment: Note that when you make the window too narrow, the solutions of both myself and Sotiris will result in a div with no width.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that's a fair drawback looking at what I am planning to do. Plus, something like min-width for a dlobal div container might take place ;)

Answer (score 5):

from the moment you need to use `position:absolute;` why not use the properties `left` & `right` instead of padding?

**html**

```
<div style="height:73px;position:absolute;left:413px;right:413px;"><div style="width:100%; height:73px; background:url(top-fill-small.png);border:1px solid red">Content  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content  Content Content Content Content Content </div></div>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/anega3

***edit***

an alternative if you need badly to use padding you can set `left:0; right:0;` and then use the paddings you already have.

**html**

```
<div style="height:73px;position:absolute;left:0;right:0px;padding-left:413px;padding-right:413px;"><div style="width:100%; height:73px; background:url(top-fill-small.png);border:1px solid red">Content  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content  Content Content Content Content Content </div></div>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/anega3/2

Comment: Wait, every time I used both, only one of them worked? Wow, thanks. I didn't think I was that nooby ;)

Comment: @Dwarf Vader: When you use both `left` and `right`, *both* of them will work.